# sqlConnection->Open() не работает

Tags: c++, mysql, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017, ado.net

Через Visual Studio->Средства->Подключение к базам данных->MySQL Database (MySQL Data Provider) заполняю поля server,user,password. Подключение успешно устанавливается. В обозревателе серверов видно нужную базу. Запросы и команды в таблицы через Правую_кнопку_мыши->Создать запрос отправляются.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

НО...!!!

Пытаюсь открыть соединение из кода программы к той же базе MySQL для работы с ней.(что собственно и нужно). Копирую connectionstring из свойств базы. ОШИБКА
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Облазил connectionstring.com, пробовал другие варианты connectionstring( user id, password и все все все), брендмауер выключен, антивирус выключен, коннекторы MySql установлены, Ado.Net коннекторы установлены, права доступа выданы. Горю второй день и не могу понять в чем дело.
Фрагмент кода где пытаюсь создать и вызвать соединение:

```
String^ connectionstring = "server=localhost;user id=root;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=users";
SqlConnection^sqlConnection = gcnew SqlConnection(connectionstring);
sqlConnection->Open();
```

Comment: Может быть следует указать порт подключения? И меня смущает пробел в user id.

Comment: В configuration manager: Named pipes c  TCP/IP включены?

Comment: Включены, user id пишется раздельно.

Answer (score 0):

Спустя 3 дня горения и втыкания в разнообразные коннекторы решение найдено!!!!

1.Идем на https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/MySql/, скачиваем их коннектор в бесплатной простой версии

2.`using namespaces Devar::Data::MySql;` подключаем пространство коннектора в проекте

3.

```
String^ connectionstring = "User Id=root;Password=12345;Host=127.0.0.1;database=users;"; // прописали строку подключения
MySqlConnection^Connection = gcnew MySqlConnection(connectionstring); // создали объект подключения с принимаемой строкой
Connection->Open(); // открываем подключение
MySqlCommand^command = /*....... // запросы в базу
....*/
Connection->Close(); // закрыли подключение
```

4. Хэлп файл к коннектору https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/MySql/docs/

PS. Почему заработал только этот коннектор не знаю, возможно проблемы именно с моей Visual Studio или MySQL Serverом.